# What is the difference between `sudoedit` and `sudo vim`?

Tags: linux, vim, sudo

What is the difference between `sudo vim /etc/services` and `sudoedit /etc/services`? I tried to edit the `/etc/services` file in linux. `sudoedit` is allowing to edit, but `sudo vim` is not allowing to edit.

Comment: I think you will get more help with this type of question at Super User.

Comment: `sudoedit` allows you to `sudo` as another user.

Comment: This [blog post](http://www.wingtiplabs.com/blog/posts/2013/03/13/sudoedit/) answers very well this question. In summary, `sudoedit` creates a temporary copy of the file you're editing that is owned by the normal user (not the root user), and save the original file when you exit the editor. Since, the editor is run as a normal user when you edit the temporary copy, `.vimrc` is loaded normally and you get to keep the syntax highlighting and other vim plugins (which shouldn't be the case if you do a `sudo vim`).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`sudoedit` specifies `sudo` with the `-e` option. From the man page:

```
 -e          The -e (edit) option indicates that, instead of running a command, the
             user wishes to edit one or more files.  In lieu of a command, the string
             "sudoedit" is used when consulting the security policy.  If the user is
             authorized by the policy, the following steps are taken.
```

Therefore, it allows the system administrator to only allow sudo rights for editing certain files, not specific commands or all files in general. It allows the administrator to control which files a user (or groups of users) can edit with elevated privileges.

What's more, the user can still use his/her preferred editor, not one that is specified by the administrator. It also runs this editor as the user itself, meaning that any options or commands specified in a `.vimrc` by the user for example will apply.

Answer (score 9):

`sudo vim /etc/services` is telling the shell to use vim editor in superuser privilege to edit the file given.

Whereas, `sudoedit /etc/services` is telling the shell to use whatever editor is stored in the EDITOR environmental variable to edit the file using super user privileges.

Comment: Ya .. this is also correct.. I checked by setting the `EDITOR` variable. After setting the `EDITOR` variable to `vim`, I can see the file is opened in `vim` otherwise it is opened in `vi`.